# Jersery REST client is returning HTTP error code : 500

Tags: rest, jersey-client

I need to create Jersey REST client. Here is my code:

```
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user_id, api_key));
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri);

    String inputString = "{ \"subject\" : \"Test\", \"message\" : \"Hello\", \"recipients\" : \"abc@gmail.com\" }";

    ClientResponse response =  webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(ClientResponse.class, inputString);

    // check response status code
    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
    }
```

Above code gives me below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 500
```

REST service is not developed by me. It is third party service. REST service says:

API can be accessed over HTTPS with Basic HTTP Auth (the Authentication header for the requests, very standard for REST-like API). API requires HTTP POST.

This is the CURL which is working fine:

curl -u user_id:api_key -d "subject=API%20Test&message=Hello&recipients=abc@gmail.com" apiEndpointUri

Please help me on Jersey REST client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your service didn't accept the POST with JSON type.

You can try with Form URLEncoded type

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> postBody = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
postBody.add("subject", "Test");
postBody.add("message", "Hello");
postBody.add("recipients", "abc@gmail.com");

ClientResponse response =  webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, postBody);
```